# Operator Overloading - no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm fairly new/in the process of learning C++ on a university level and in one of my assignments i keep getting an error that I have no idea how to solve, I'd appreciate it if you veterans and/or geniuses could help me/nudge me in the right direction.

I seem to be having a problem in the implimentation of my class functions, specifically the operator overloads.
The following is my header file:

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

#include "book.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Library;

class Library
{
    private:
        string name;
        Book** books;
        int librarySize;
        int numBooks;
    public:
        //Constructor, Copy constructor and Destructor
        Library(string a);
        Library(const Library& obj);
        ~Library();

        //Operator overloads
        Library& operator+=( Book right);
        Library& operator-=(Book right);
        Library& operator=(const Library &right);
        Library& operator++(int);
        Library& operator--();

        //Accessors
        Book* getBook(string);
        bool isFull();
        void print();



};

#endif
```

And the error seems to be coming from around here in my .cpp file:

```
#include"library.h"
#include "book.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



 Library::Library(string a)
{
    name = a;
}

Library::Library(const Library& obj)
{

    name = obj.name;
    librarySize = obj.librarySize;
    numBooks = obj.numBooks;

    //Copy Books* array
    for(int x=0; x!= librarySize; x++)
        *(books+x) = *(obj.books+x);

}
//Operator overloads
Library& Library::operator+=( Book right)
{

    if(numBooks == librarySize)
         cout<<"Library is full!\n";
    else
    {
        numBooks++;     
        *books[numBooks] = right;
    }
    return *this;

}



Library& Library::operator-=(Book right)
{
    if(numBooks != 0)
    {
        for(int x=0; x!= numBooks; x++)
        {
            if(*books[x] != right){}
            else
                *books[x] = "";
        }
    }
    else
        cout<<"Library is empty!\n";
    return *this;
}

Library& Library::operator=(const Library &right)
{

    name = right.name;
    librarySize = right.librarySize;
    numBooks = right.numBooks;
    for(int x=0; x!= librarySize; x++)
        *(books+x) = *(right.books+x);
    return *this;
}

Library& Library::operator++(int)
{

    librarySize++;
    return *this;

}

Library& Library::operator--()
{

    if(numBooks == librarySize)
    {   
        *books[numBooks] = right;
        numBooks--;
    }
    librarySize--;
    return *this;
}
```

I get this as an error followed by a whole lot of "note:"s

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/Prac3# g++ -std=c++11 -c library.cpp library.h
library.cpp: In member function ‘Library& Library::operator-=(Book)’:
library.cpp:48:17: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘Book’ and ‘Book’)
```

I have been looking around for answers since the past 2 days but both my profesors and the internet havent given me a solution yet.Ive also tryed different ways of doing the same but i get other errors as well as this one. Though it seems that when i remove the "-=" overload it doesnt give me all the notes, it just gives me the above error.

Thanks in advance.

(I'm new to this whole 'blogging' routine so if i made any netiqette errors or if u need more info please comment prefferably without the bad language :)

Comment: Do you *have* a comparison operator to compare two `Book` objects?

Comment: Also, why do you have an array of *pointers* to `Book`? Do you make all the pointers in the array point somewhere valid before you start dereferencing them? Do you allocate memory for the array?

Comment: Sorry, i think it will make more sense if i post the full .cpp file.

Comment: Please don't post your whole code, instead try to minimize it to the smalles possible example you can that still have your error. Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Or at least only show us the relevant parts (which would be the `Book` class definition and the `Library::operator-=` function)

Comment: Sorry, will keep that in mind next time, the pointer to books is a spec i the assignment so i dont hav much choice in the matter...and im trying to compare a string to the books name, but even if i put "*books[x].name != right" (names being already declared and working in the books class) it gives me the same error

Comment: As for the unrelated questions I brought up, regarding the pointers, you indeed do not initialize these pointers anywhere. So once you get your program to build, you will get lots of crashes because you use uninitialized pointers and have *undefined behavior*. If the assignment is to make you learn about pointers, then you should have learned about `new` and `new[]` too. If the assignment is to teach you about operator overloading then use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, and don't use pointers anywhere.

Comment: I see, I actually prefer vectors but for some seemingly unknown reason we are not allowed to use them in my course...i will do as u say and initialise the pointer array though

Comment: Also, i think i understand the problem now (when u asked if i hav a comparison operator) but i am not allowed to edit the book.h class so i dont see how i can do anything in this situation, any advice?

Comment: You can always create a non-member comparison operator function. Or call some member function of `Book` to get the name of each of the books and compare those strings instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the -= operator overload implementation, you are comparing to see if two Books are !=. It seems the compiler cannot find any implementation of this, so I am assuming you have not written your != or == overload for Book.